# Libgdx Box2d - Welded Joints Spinning out of control (Does the blue lines mean anything?)

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have started to play around with box2d yesterday, and I ran myself into a situation where my vehicle spins out of control

So here is how my vehicle looks:

[image]

The squares and the triangles are welded together with a WeldJoint (red circles shown below)

The circle is connected to the triangle through RevoluteJoint (blue circles shown below)

[image]

I know that the wheels+triangles works, because they do fine on their own
I also know that squares welded together is fine because they do well on their own too

However the issue is then I weld the triangles to squares, everything just goes haywire. The following images sums up what happens afterwards:

[image]
[image]

And eventually this happens:

[image]

I can't seem to find whats wrong. I searched some information up about welded objects spinning out of control in box2d, however, I only found cases where people decided to try to alter the time step in box2d. I kept the time step at 1/60f and never changed that.

I suspect that something is wrong with the blue lines? And what are the blue lines? Any help is appreciated

P.S. I would prefer to not put my code in here, because it took me 7 classes to do this ... so it would be very very confusing if I try to post them all here. I can post parts of it, but I don't know which parts I need to show.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 errors

1. The joints were not connecting the right points on the cubes, be careful about `weldJointDef.localAnchorA.set(anchor1); weldJointDef.localAnchorB.set(anchor2);`
2. The Bodies are condensed into that corner where all the blue lines meet, the squares are the fixtures. The fixtures are not aligned with the body. Due to the distance, the between the fixtures and the bodies, when the fixtures hit something the force is amplified through the body, and the joint goes crazy